# GCC: why constant variables not placed in .rodata

Tags: c, memory, gcc, constants, readonly

I've always believed that GCC would place a `static const` variable to `.rodata` segments (or to `.text` segments for optimizations) of an ELF or such file. But it seems not that case.

I'm currently using `gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20120505 (prerelease)` on a laptop with GNU/Linux. And it does place a static constant variable to `.bss` segment:

```
/*
 * this is a.c, and in its generated asm file a.s, the following line gives:
 *   .comm a,4,4 
 * which would place variable a in .bss but not .rodata(or .text)
 */
static const int a;

int main()
{
    int *p = (int*)&a;
    *p = 0;  /* since a is in .data, write access to that region */
             /* won't trigger an exception */
    return 0;
}
```

So, is this a bug or a feature? I've decided to file this as a bug to bugzilla but it might be better to ask for help first.

Are there any reasons that GCC can't place a const variable in `.rodata`?

**UPDATED:**

As tested, a constant variable with an explicit initialization(like `const int a = 0;`) would be placed into `.rodata` by GCC, while I left the variable uninitialized. Thus this question might be closed later -- I didn't present a correct question maybe.

Also, in my previous words I wrote that the variable a is placed in '.data' section, which is incorrect. It's actually placed into `.bss` section since not initialized. Text above now is corrected.

Comment: In C++, you can initialize a `const` variable from a value that is not a compile-time constant. But I checked, and GCC doesn't allow that as an extension in C mode.

Comment: @Potatoswatter In C you could also write this legally: `void test(int a){ const int b = a; /* ... */ }`. I'm actually wondering whether a global constant variable shall be places into a readonly memory region.

Comment: FWIW, it does go into a read-only section if you initialize it explicitly.

Comment: @Mat Oh.. I'm.. so stupid, and, greatly grateful to you!

Comment: Well there's still something fishy. AFAICT, initializing to 0 doesn't change the program at all, that static var should be initialized to zero if you don't explicitly do so. So _something_ is going on. (clang puts it in a RO section regardless of initialization.)

Comment: `static const int a;` isn't even legal, I think - constants must have an initializer.

Comment: Also, programming errors in C++ do *not* "trigger an exceptions". Exceptions are part of *correct* programming, not debugging tools.

Comment: Finally, at best variables with static storage duration that are initialized in the *static initialization phase* are eligible for putting in a read-only segment. "Constant expression" is the relevant term.

Comment: @KerrekSB: RE `static const int a;` might not be legal: doesn't that constitute a tentative definition and behave as in §6.9.2 (i.e. as long as there is no conflict, behaves as if it had a zero initializer)?

Comment: @KerrekSB: C is not C++. `static const int a;` is perfectly legal C.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Non-constant initializers are perfectly legal in C for non-static objects (i.e., objects defined inside a function without the `static` keyword): `const int r = rand();`. Non-constant initializers are not permitted for static objects. The presence or absence of `const` doesn't matter; in C, `const` means *read-only*, not "constant".

Answer (score 12):

The compiler has made it a common, which can be merged with other compatible symbols, and which can go in bss (taking no space on disk) if it ends up with no explicitly initialized definition. Putting it in rodata would be a trade-off; you'd save memory (commit charge) at runtime, but would use more space on disk (potentially a lot for a huge array).

If you'd rather it go in rodata, use the `-fno-common` option to GCC.

Comment: `-fno-common` is passed to the assembler but not the compiler I think, since after `-fno-common` it still generates `.comm   a,4,4` in the asm file. Also, though this time the assembler merges `.bss` into `.data`, write access to a still successes, which means a is placed into `.data` but not `.rodata`. The problem I think is that it's not initialized.

Answer (score 7):

Why *GCC* does it? Can't really answer that question without asking the developers themselves. If I'm allowed to speculate, I'd wager it has to do with optimization--compilers don't *have* to enforce const.

That said, I think it's better if we look at the language itself, particularly undefined behavior. There are a *few* mentions of undefined behavior, but none of them go in-depth.

Modifying a constant *is* undefined behavior. [Const is a contract](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/), and that is especially true in C (and C++).

> "But what if I `const_cast` away the const and modify y anyway?" Then you have undefined behavior.

What *undefined behavior* **means** is that the compiler is allowed to do quite literally anything it wants, and whatever the compiler decides to do will not be considered a violation of the ISO 9899 standard.

> **3.4.3**
>
> 1 undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, **for which this International Standard imposes no requirements**
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
>
> *ISO/IEC 9899:1999, §3.4.3*

What this means is that, because you have invoked undefined behavior, anything the compiler does is technically correct by way of *not* being *incorrect*. Ergo, it is correct for GCC to take...

```
static const int a = 0;
```

...and turn it into a `.rodata` symbol, while taking...

```
static const int a; // guaranteed to be zero
```

...and turning it into a `.bss` symbol.

In the former case, any attempt to modify `a`--even by proxy--will typically result in a segmentation violation, causing the kernel to force-kill the running program. In the latter case, the program will probably run without crashing.

That said, it is not reasonable to guess which one the compiler will do. *Const is a contract*, and it is up to you, the programmer, to uphold that contract by not modifying data that is supposed to be constant. Violating that contract means undefined behavior, and all the portability issues and program bugs that come with it.

So GCC can do a couple things.

**It might** write the symbol to .rodata, giving it protection under the OS kernel

**It might** write the object to somewhere where memory protection is not guaranteed, in which case...

**It might** change the value

**It might** change the value and immediately change it back

**It might** completely delete the offending code under the rationale that the value isn't changing (`0 -> 0`), essentially optimizing...

```
int main(){
    int *p = &a;
    *p = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

...to...

```
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

**It might** even send a model T-800 back in time to terminate your parents before you're born.

All of these behaviors are legal (well, *legal* in the sense of adhering to the standard), so the bug report was not warranted.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question, which was *why* gcc behaves as it does. Of course the standard permits a wide range of behaviors.

Comment: There's no way to definitively answer the 'why' without asking the developers of GCC themselves. However, I *can* give reasoning derived from the standard itself, and undefined behavior is certainly an important angle to look at. IMHO, focusing on implementation details like this is risky, because one might base unreasonable assumptions on that knowledge and rely on the semantics of one particular implementation.

Answer (score 4):

writing to an object that has been declared `const` qualified is undefined behavior: anything can happen, even that.

There is no way in C to declare the object itself to be unmutable, you only forbid it to be mutable through the particular access that you have to it. Here you have an `int*`, so modification is "allowed" in the sense that the compiler is not forced to issue a diagnostic. Doing a cast in C means that you suppose to know what you are doing.

Comment: Actually, the code above did NOT explicitly write to the const qualified variable a. See @Mat's comment above, which I think shall be the exact answer I need.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN: Jens is right, what you're doing is undefined behavior. Why GCC doesn't put that var in a RO section when you don't initialize it, but does when you do, is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Mat Yes I believe Jens is right about that undefined behavior, what I mean was, effect of that undefined behavior shall be at run-time but not compile-time.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN. it explicitly writes to that object, only that the result of that write operation is not observable in this particular program, because the object is never evaluated afterwards. So the compiler would be allowed to optimize that out if the variable would not be `const` qualified.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any reasons that GCC can't place a const variable in .rodata?

Your program is optimized by the compiler (even in `-O0` some optimizations are done). Constant propagation is done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

Try to deceive the compiler like this (note that this program is still technically undefined behavior):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int a;

int main(void)
{
    *(int *) &a = printf("");  // compiler cannot assume it is 0

    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove all the code since line 4, and gcc still gives variable a in `.data`. I don't think it depends on the way how we access it, but on how we declare it. See @Mat's comment above, which I think shall be the exact answer I need.

Comment: I'm seeing a write through that pointer in the assembly with `-O0`, it's not optimized out for me.

Comment: @Mat an implementation has the right to optimized out all the lines in Pengyu's program (i.e., equivalent to `int main(void) {}`) as the observable behavior of the program is not changed. Actually in my compilation of Pengyu's program `a` is  even put in `.bss` as it takes less space in the final binary than in `.rodata`.

Comment: @ouah Thank you for point this out. I said `.data` only because I see that`.comm` derective, and in this case since I didn't initialize a, it shall be put into `.bss`. My words was wrong about that.

Comment: I don't think that the fact that the value is known (and constant) triggers the optimization. In fact the compiler can even deduce that the value is never read, so the assignment can be optimized out. This is what changes with the `printf`.

Comment: @JensGustedt I know that access is not reduced by reading the asm code it generates. Also, I've tested your code and nothing unexpected happens.