# const_cast: modifying a formerly const value is only undefined if the original variable is const

Tags: c++, c++11

https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/462608

> modifying a formerly const value is only undefined if the original variable is const

...

> if you use it to take the const off a reference to something that wasn't declared with const, it is safe.

...

> This can be useful when overloading member functions based on const, for instance. It can also be used to add const to an object, such as to call a member function overload.

I am unable to understand the meanings of the above quotes. I request you to give me examples to practically show what these quotes mean.

Comment: [The example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast#Example) on cppreference.com provides some useful exposition.

Comment: Regarding the first point, it's important to understand WHY const_casting a const variable is undefined. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56141131/3672674) explains it nicely

Comment: "formerly" is a typo, it probably is meant to be "formally"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your first two quotes:

```
void do_not_do_this(const int& cref) {
    const_cast<int&>(cref) = 42;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    // "if you use it to take the const off a reference 
    // to something that wasn't declared with const, it is safe."
    do_not_do_this(a);  // well-defined
        // a is now 42.
    
    // "modifying a formerly const value is only 
    //  undefined if the original variable is const"
    const int b = 0;
    do_not_do_this(a);  // undefined behavoiur
}
```

Regarding your final quote:

```
// "This can be useful when overloading member functions based
//  on const, for instance. It can also be used to add const
//  to an object, such as to call a member function overload."
class A {
    const int& get() const
    {
        // ... some common logic for const and
        // non-const overloads.
        return a_;
    }

    int& get() {
        // Since this get() overload is non-const, the object itself
        // is non-const in this scope. Moreover, the a_ member
        // is non-const, and thus casting away the const of the return
        // from the const get() (after 'this' has been casted to
        // const) is safe.
        A const * const c_this = this;
        return const_cast<int&>(c_this->get());
    }
    
private:
    int a_{0}; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(const int& ub, const int& ok)
{
    const_cast<int&>(ub) = 0.0; // undefined behaviour - the original object is const
    const_cast<int&>(ok) = 1.0; // this is fine - the original object is not const
}

int main()
{
    const int ub = 1.0;
    int ok = 0.0;
    foo(ub, ok);
    std::cout << ub << " " << ok << std::ends;
}
```

Note the output on common compilers is `1 1`: the rationale being that the compiler knows that `ub` cannot change in `main` so it substitutes 1 for `ub` in the `std::cout` call.

Your third paragraph is alluding to a function body of a non-`const` member function calling the `const` version as a means of obviating code repetition.